# Web visitor statistics for Django?

Tags: django, statistics

I'm looking for some good app to handle visitor statistics for a Django project. Any hints?

Comment: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/analytics/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside Django:

- http://code.google.com/p/django-tracking/

Outside Django:

- http://piwik.org/
- http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but I would like to vouch for Piwik. It has made significant improvements in recent years, and I have found that it loads some 50% quicker than Google Analytics.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution today is [django-analytical](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-analytical/)